# Aligning hr bar with css menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu, menubar

I am having problems trying to align an `<hr>` divider with a menu bar.

I want the `<hr>` divider to be directly under the menu bar with NO spacing in between.

[Here's my code/what it looks like on jsfiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/8ymHe/)

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a thick border instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Is a bad practice to use markup for visual-only elements. (that is, elements that provide no content, just design)

For a visual feature like that, I would use `border-bottom`:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ymHe/1/

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Check it, is pretty much what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a `border-bottom` to `.container`? Otherwise you'll have to set a negative top margin on the `hr`.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
hr{
 margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: you might have to do a negative margin-top.